# Add custom domain names to web apps using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I am new person to Azure development. Is it possible to add custom domain names to web apps using .Net REST API?

Comment: Hi there. Would you consider replying to the person below you helped you, and/or tick their answer to mark it as correct?

Comment: No reply, so voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do that.

1) Install the NuGet [Web Sites Management Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/) into your project.

2) Get Azure Publish Settings file (for example, by using Powershell Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile). You will need that later (the value of the management certificate field inside of that file).

2) Instantiate WebSiteManagementClient. [That](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/Models/WebSiteUpdateParameters.cs) should help with the understanding of the code.

3) Next, the code is below. I just tested and it works. First, it lists the webspaces, then the websites inside of each of webspace, and you should copy and paste the website webspace into the

```
public const string base64EncodedCertificate = "ManagementCertificateValueFromPublishSettingsFile";
    public const string subscriptionId = "AzureSubscriptionId";

    static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials()
    {
        return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate)));
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebSiteManagementClient client = new WebSiteManagementClient(getCredentials());

        WebSpacesListResponse n = client.WebSpaces.List();
        n.Select(p =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("webspace {0}", p.Name);
            WebSpacesListWebSitesResponse websitesInWebspace = client.WebSpaces.ListWebSites(p.Name,
                  new WebSiteListParameters()
                  {
                  });
            websitesInWebspace.Select(o =>
            {
                Console.Write(o.Name);     

                return o;
            }).ToArray();
            return p;
        }).ToArray();

        Console.ReadLine();
        var configuration = client.WebSites.Get("WebSpaceName", "WebSiteName", new WebSiteGetParameters());

        configuration.WebSite.HostNames.Add("new domain");
        var resp = client.WebSites.Update("WebSpaceName", "WebSiteName", new WebSiteUpdateParameters() { HostNames = configuration.WebSite.HostNames });
        Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to simply add 1 custom domain name rather than update all? Seems that it runs a CNAME check every time it updates so is a little heavy if you have 20 custom domains.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-powershell-configure-custom-domain

Most easily done with PowerShell.

```
$fqdn="<Replace with your custom domain name>"
$webappname="mywebapp$(Get-Random)"
$location="West Europe"

# Create a resource group.
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $webappname -Location $location

# Create an App Service plan in Free tier.
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -Location $location `
-ResourceGroupName $webappname -Tier Free

# Create a web app.
New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName $webappname

Write-Host "Configure a CNAME record that maps $fqdn to $webappname.azurewebsites.net"
Read-Host "Press [Enter] key when ready ..."

# Before continuing, go to your DNS configuration UI for your custom domain and follow the 
# instructions at https://aka.ms/appservicecustomdns to configure a CNAME record for the 
# hostname "www" and point it your web app's default domain name.

# Upgrade App Service plan to Shared tier (minimum required by custom domains)
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname `
-Tier Shared

# Add a custom domain name to the web app. 
Set-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname `
-HostNames @($fqdn,"$webappname.azurewebsites.net")
```