# Add Custom domain in dynamically created web app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created azure web app using the REST API. Is there is any option to custom domain mapping using rest api ?.

From the below Link,  I have created the new web app service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate

Comment: Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839883/add-custom-domain-names-to-web-apps-using-rest-api?rq=1) with you, you could refer to it.

Comment: yes, but it using certificates. I am using token based authentication.

Comment: so whats the question? yes you can do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @4c74356b41 provided, you could use [Web Apps - Create Or Update Host Name Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatehostnamebinding) to achieve what you want. I test in my site and it works fine, you could refer to the following steps.

1.Go to the webapp that you have created in portal and **add permission** to the app registered in Azure AD.

[image]

2.Go to your DNS configuration UI for your custom domain and follow that [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name#add-a-dns-record-for-your-custom-domain).

[image]

3.You could follow the code as below.

**Note**:The hostNameBindings name here is the whole CNAME in your custom domain DNS zone like `joey.example.com`

```
var appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://management.azure.com/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl +@"subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxxxxxxxxx/hostNameBindings/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2016-08-01";
    string body = "{\"properties\": {\"azureResourceName\": \"joey\"}}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PutAsync(requestURl, stringContent).Result;
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: That works for the domain with CNAME added already in the dns zone file. Suppose if a CNAME record is not added for the sub domain, note that we already put * for the main domain.  Is there any way to automatically point the domain?

Comment: Create the CNAME record
Add a CNAME record to map a wildcard name to the app's default hostname (<app_name>.azurewebsites.net).

For the *.contoso.com domain example, the CNAME record will map the name * to <app_name>.azurewebsites.net.

When the CNAME is added, the DNS records page looks like the following example:

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-wildcard-domain

Comment: As you have said, you set `*.contoso.com` in DNS record, then you could add several sub domain like `hello.contoso.com` as hostname.

Comment: We already added it earlier. The request response was "bad request". Any solution?

Comment: I am not very clear where you get the bad request. When you have added `*.contoso.com` in DNS record, you could add `hello.contoso.com` as hostname in  rest api in VS. I test and do not get error message.

Comment: Though the request body is not require, when you add custom domain through rest api, you need to add the request body in put method.

Comment: We have appended the code- "{\"properties\": {\"metadata\": {\"key1\": \"value1\"},\"TTL\": 3600,\"CNAMERecord\": {\"cname\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"}}}". It's working fine now. Thank you for your valuable informations.

Comment: Any idea to add wildcard ssl binding ?

Comment: To get an appId, tenantId and secret, you should follow steps from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/register-a-client-app

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/app-service-powershell-configure-custom-domain

you can use that article to configure it.

```
$fqdn="<Replace with your custom domain name>"
$webappname="mywebapp$(Get-Random)"
$location="West Europe"

# Create a resource group.
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $webappname -Location $location

# Create an App Service plan in Free tier.
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -Location $location `
-ResourceGroupName $webappname -Tier Free

# Create a web app.
New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName $webappname

Write-Host "Configure a CNAME record that maps $fqdn to $webappname.azurewebsites.net"
Read-Host "Press [Enter] key when ready ..."

# Before continuing, go to your DNS configuration UI for your custom domain and follow the 
# instructions at https://aka.ms/appservicecustomdns to configure a CNAME record for the 
# hostname "www" and point it your web app's default domain name.

# Upgrade App Service plan to Shared tier (minimum required by custom domains)
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname `
-Tier Shared

# Add a custom domain name to the web app. 
Set-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname `
-HostNames @($fqdn,"$webappname.azurewebsites.net")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Since the code you provided is the power shell shift. We need to integrate the code using azure rest api. Can you please provide me any solution to cater the issue that I am facing?

Comment: I assume you are looking for this rest call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatehostnamebinding