# Azure AD, When I use custom domain in Azure WebApp to access, I can't get the correct token

Tags: azure

I built a WebApp on Microsoft Azure, this WebApp needs to access a WebApi to get data, I used Azure AD authentication, everything works fine, but when I bind a custom domain to this WebApp, I go to use This custom domain to access the Token obtained by the WebApp is not correct.

Correct and incorrect token comparison：

Correct:

```
"aud": "api://[client id]",
"scp": "user_impersonation",
```

incorrect:

```
"nonce": "2o-O2KpKPQekxB_vLD9myPz2zq4n333dUphtn7FhJk",
"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"scp": "email openid profile",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Custom domain in dynamically created web app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037918/add-custom-domain-in-dynamically-created-web-app-service)

Comment: [Troubleshoot domain and TLS/SSL certificate problems in Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037918/add-custom-domain-in-dynamically-created-web-app-service)