# Dynamically create sub domain in c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, webforms

I am working on Multi-Tenancy application. I have a requirement to create a subdomain on Azure  when the user registered for example test1.example.com I already deploy my subdomain application to  test.example.com I need to create subdomain dynamically

Comment: What did you use? Azure App Service or Azure Virtual Machine?

Comment: Azure App Service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom domain names to web apps using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839883/add-custom-domain-names-to-web-apps-using-rest-api)

Comment: It is too broad to give you an answer, as that requires multiple steps: 1) manipulate DNS to generate new sub domains (CNAME records for example), which depends on what DNS service you use for this domain, and whether that service allows you to automate sub domain creation. 2) Add such sub domains to your Azure App Service (duplicate to existing thread).