# How to set Custom Base URL in Azure App Service with .Net Core?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web application in .Net core(v5.0) and hosted it in Azure App Service. I have created a view and that allows me to add a new URL based on that create a new subdomain in the same service and publish code in that. This concept also uses in Jira software where our `<projectname>.atlassian.com`

**Eg**:

I have added dev in a text box then-new subdomain added like. `dev.<myappservicename>.azurewebsites.net`
In this case, all code copy and run this code properly.

**Main Domain:**

Base URL(Created URL): `<myappservicename>.azurewebsites.net`

Custom URL(Added from View): `dev.<myappservicename>.azurewebsites.net`
,
`admin.<myappservicename>.azurewebsites.net`

**Technology Specification:**

1. .Net Core(5.0)
2. C#
3. Azure App Service

If anyone has an idea then suggest thought.
It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [restapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/domains/createorupdate) or [.net sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58672600/creating-sub-domains-on-azure-programmatically-in-net-core) to create subdomain.**

From your description, I see that there should be no need to redeploy your webapp, so if there is a business need, it is recommended to identify it through the program, what is the input url of the browser, to process your program.

Eg:

1. `company1.<projec_tname>.azurewebsites.net`

   Get HttpRequest url to handle company1's bussiness.
2. company2.<projec_tname>.azurewebsites.net

   Get HttpRequest url to handle company2's bussiness.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonPan For Your answer. Actually here my confusion is how I am able to create a new subdomain "company1/2/3" in Azure App Service?

Comment: @DeepSoni As my answer said, you can use restapi, this post has more detail for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037918/add-custom-domain-in-dynamically-created-web-app-service

Comment: Actually I have purchased only one app service and then I add DNS for this. When I give that domain name in app service's custom domain section it gives me an error of "Domain ownership"

Comment: @DeepSoni Let me try, wait.

Comment: @DeepSoni You want create it by code, right?

Comment: Yes I have to create it by code and I have an azure account and one app service and service Url is: <mywebsite>.azurewebsites.net and U gave to set <admin>.<mywebsite>.azurewebsites.net or create new from code when admin has to create this new environment.

Comment: https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ManagementLibrarySample/Program.cs

Comment: @DeepSoni It is possible to use restapi, but it is too much trouble. Use .net sdk. You can try the link above, or search for better reference documents.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried your way but when I tried to call API it gives me Forbidden(403) and if tried from azure API service and put correct values in this still it gives me a Not Found(404) error.

Comment: @DeepSoni Maybe you need contact microsoft engineer by raising a support ticket on portal. Let them help you to check the issues.

Comment: @DeepSoni I just know that this is feasible. The specific reason may be factors such as parameters or subscription restrictions. Let the official help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @JasonPan You have any idea about how to create Azure App Service From C# using RestAPI.